# Replace forward slash "/" in a file

Tags: text-processing, vi, replace, special-characters

I'm using `vi` editor, I have a data like this in a file.

```
05/08/2017,U,01,116326001 
05/08/2017,U,01,116226001 
05/08/2017,U,01,116726323 
05/08/2017,U,01,116236001
```

I want to replace the date(1st column).

Ex: `05/08/2017` to `04/03/2017`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say “I want to replace the date(1st column). Ex: `05/08/2017` to `04/03/2017`.  Do you specifically want to replace `05/08/2017` with `04/03/2017`?  Or `05/08` with `04/03`? Or *any* date with `04/03/2017`?

Answer (score 4):

Inside Vi (or Vim):

```
:%s#^05/08/2017#04/03/2017#
```

You may have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> first to get out of insert mode.

Just like in `sed`, you may choose an arbitrary character as the pattern delimiter when substituting using the `s` command. Here I've chosen `#`.

The pattern, `^05/08/2017`, will match at the start of the line due to the `^`. This prevents it from accidentally matching elsewhere on any line.

With the usual `/` as pattern delimiter, we get a nice example of what's called "[the leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)":

```
:%s/^05\/08\/2017/04\/03\/2017/
```

The substitution command will be carried out on all lines in the current Vi buffer since we use `%` at the start for the "range" (`%` is identical to `1,$`, i.e. "from the first line to the last line").

Answer (score 1):

Simply with ***sed*** tool:

```
sed -i 's~^[0-9]*/[0-9]*~04/03~' file
```

- `-i` option, to modify the file in-place

---

The `file` contents after processing:

```
04/03/2017,U,01,116326001 
04/03/2017,U,01,116226001 
04/03/2017,U,01,116726323 
04/03/2017,U,01,116236001
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk option:

```
awk -F, '{ printf "%s","04/03/2017";for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf ",%s",$i } }' filename
```

Print the date for want and then loop through and print the remaining fields separated by ,